# Yii2: do not redirect to login for a certain action in controller

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, php-7.4

I have a custom controller and I'm trying to define an action in the controller that could be accessed by the guest users.
My controller code is the following:

```php
class MyCustomController extends Controller
{
    ...
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::class,
                'only' => ['live'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'allow' => true,
                        'actions' => ['live'],
                        'roles' => ['?'],
                    ],
                ]
            ]
        ];
    }


    /**
     * Live action.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionLive()
    {
        return $this->render('live');
    }
...
}
```

And the view code is this:

```php
<?php

echo 'We are live!!';

?>
```

I also have this setting in `frontend/config/main.php`

```php
return [
...
'as beforeRequest' => [
        'class' => 'yii\filters\AccessControl',
        'rules' => [
            [
                'actions' => ['login', 'error'],
                'allow' => true,
            ],
            [
                'allow' => true,
                'roles' => ['@'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
...
]
```

When I try to access the page `http://my-webapp/my-custom/live` as an authenticated user I get the message `Forbidden (#403)` which is ok (although displaying it for the authenticated users would be perfectly ok too).

But when I access that page as a guest user I get redirected to the login page. I just want to disable the redirect for this particular action and just let the guest users see that view.

Comment: Do not place access rules in two places unless necessary (e.g. site offline) - remove from `config/main.php` and leave in Controller only. You may want to take a look at `matchCallback` https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-filters-accessrule#$matchCallback-detail - allows fine tuning custom access rules. Your description what you want to achieve seems contradictive - authenticated user is forbidden, guest user is always redirected to login page. That's default behaviour. You want also show exception 404 for guest users?

Comment: No, I don't want to show exception 404 to the guest users. It is exactly the opposite. I want them to be able to acces thar page. As for the authenticated users, it doesn't matter. I'm perfectly fine if they are able to access it or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying `AccessControl` filter twice.

First filter is set for `Application` so it is applied for each request with following rules:

1. If the action id is "login" or "error" allow any user.
2. Allow logged in users
3. Deny any other request.

The second filter is for `MyCustomController` and it's set to apply only for requests to action `live` of that controller with following rules:

1. Allow any user who is not logged in.
2. Deny any other request.

So when request comes from user who is logged in, the request is stopped by second filter and the 403 error is displayed.
When request comes from guest user it is stopped by first filter and user is redirected to login page.

To allow guests access your action you should add exception to first filter to make sure only second `AccessControl` filter is applied:

```php
return [
    //...
    'as beforeRequest' => [
        'class' => 'yii\filters\AccessControl',
        'except' => ['my-custom/live'],
        'rules' => [
            [
                'actions' => ['login', 'error'],
                'allow' => true,
            ],
            [
                'allow' => true,
                'roles' => ['@'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
...
];
```

Actually, if you are OK with allowing any user to see the `my-custom/live` there is no need for the second `AccessControl` filter. Just setting the exception in the first (application wide) filter will be enough.

Comment: Worked like a charm! I almost can't believe it is that simple. :-) Thanks a lot!